# What is the frequncy range of seismic vibrations?

Tags: structural-engineering, frequency-response, modal-analysis, seismic, earthquake-engineering

I'm working on a structure which needs to sustain common seismic vibrations due to earthquakes. So I want to do some modal analysis to find natural frequencies of the structure and make sure they are out of the range of seismic vibrations. I'm being told that if the natural frequencies of the structure are beyond 17 Hz it should be fine. However, I can't find any reference approving this specific number.

So I would appreciate if you could help me know what is the frequency range of seismic vibrations, providing engineering or scientific references. Thanks for your support in advance.

Answer (score 4):

The frequency and ground acceleration and other pertinent data are recorded in a seismic design espectra which is unique for each site and varies with the type of the soil on the side.

Usually building department will have that information.

For example the following is the link to Los Angeles building department site for design espectra.

https://data2.scec.org/ugms-mcerGM-tool_v18.4/